# How could I switch this program to give the option to play again or press q to quit

Tags: scheme, racket

This is a very simple program, im just new to scheme and programming in general. I want to switch this to give the option to play again or press q to quit. The program is working normally now just want to add this feature. Ill leave the whole code below

```
(#%require (lib "27.ss" "srfi"))
(#%require (only racket/base read-line))
(#%require (only racket/base read-line random))

  (define (guess-game target attempts)
    (display "Guess a number from 1 to 100:")
    (newline)
    (let loop ((attempts-left attempts)
               (low 1)
               (high 100))
      (if (= attempts-left 0)
          (begin
            (display "Out of attempts. The correct number was ")
            (display target)
            (newline)
            (display "Please enter your name:")
            (newline)
            (let ((name (read-line)))
              (display "Good game, ")
              (display name)
              (newline)
              (newline)
              (+ (random 99) 1))))
          (begin
            (display "Enter guess ")
            (flush-output)
            (define guess (string->number (read-line)))
              (if (not (integer? guess))
                  (begin
                    (display "Invalid input. Please enter a valid number.")
                    (newline)
                    (loop attempts-left low high)))
                  (if (= guess target)
                      (begin
                        (display "Correct! ")
                        (display attempts)
                        (display " guesses... Please enter your name:")
                        (newline)
                        (let ((name (read-line)))
                          (display "Good game, ")
                          (display name)
                          (newline)
                          (newline))))
                      (if (< guess target)
                          (begin
                            (display "Higher...")
                            (newline)
                            (loop (- attempts-left 1) guess high))
                          (begin
                            (display "Lower...")
                            (newline)
                            (loop (- attempts-left 1) low guess))))))
  
(guess-game(+ (random 99) 1) 5)
```

Thank you for anyone willing to help

Comment: Put a loop around your call to `guess-game`.

Comment: @ScottHunter how would I make it break out of the loop though?

Comment: How does your existing program break out of its existing loop?

Answer (score 1):

Untested and written on an buggy keyboard:

```
(define target-maximum 99)

;; first increment.
(define (guess-game target attempts)
  (display "Guess a number from 1 to 100:") ;; exclusive?
  (newline)
  (let loop ((attempts-left attempts)
             (low 1)
             (high 100))
    (if (= attempts-left 0)
        (begin
          (display "Out of attempts. The correct number was ")
          (display target)
          (newline)
          (display "Please enter your name:")
          (newline)
          (let ((name (read-line)))
            (display "Good game, ")
            (display name)
            (newline)
            (newline)
            (+ (random target-maximum) 1) ;; this line was returning a random integer.
            (display "Would you like to play again? [y/n]")
            (let ((in (read-line)))
              (if (and (string? in)
                       (or (string=? "y")    ;; the user wants to enter. We may
                           (string=? "Y")))  ;; reuse its name afterwards.
                  (guess-game (random target-maximum) 5) ;; magic numbers would be configured
                                             ;; at another place and reused here.
                  ;; the following line is the else:
                  (display "good bye, then!")))))
    (begin
      (display "Enter guess ")
      (flush-output)
      ;; this define is ill defined I suppose.
      ;; you can only define at the start of lexical scope or the global env.
      (define guess (string->number (read-line)))
      (if (not (integer? guess))
          (begin
            (display "Invalid input. Please enter a valid number.")
            (newline)
            (loop attempts-left low high)))
      (if (= guess target)
          (begin
            (display "Correct! ")
            (display attempts)
            (display " guesses... Please enter your name:")
            (newline)
            (let ((name (read-line)))
              (display "Good game, ")
              (display name)
              (newline)
              (newline))))
      (if (< guess target)
          (begin
            (display "Higher...")
            (newline)
            (loop (- attempts-left 1) guess high))
          (begin
            (display "Lower...")
            (newline)
            (loop (- attempts-left 1) low guess)))))))

;; second increment:

;; helper function declared previously.
(define (play-again
          name      ;; the name may carry over
          attempts) ;; the attempts may carry over
  (display "Would you like to play again? [y/n]")
  (let ((in (read-line)))
    (if (and (string? in)
             (or (string=? "y")    ;; the user wants to enter. We may
                 (string=? "Y"))) ;; reuse its name afterwards.
        (guess-game (random target-maximum) 5) ;; magic numbers would be configured
        ;; at another place and reused here.
        ;; the following line is the else:
        (display "good bye, then!"))))

(define (guess-game target attempts)
  (display "Guess a number from 1 to 100:") ;; exclusive?
  (newline)
  (let loop ((attempts-left attempts)
             (low 1)
             (high 100))
    (if (= attempts-left 0)
        (begin
          (display "Out of attempts. The correct number was ")
          (display target)
          (newline)
          (display "Please enter your name:")
          (newline)
          (let ((name (read-line)))
            (display "Good game, ")
            (display name)
            (newline)
            (newline)
            (+ (random target-maximum) 1) ;; this line was returning a random integer.
            (play-again name 5))) ;; still a magic number!
    (begin
      (display "Enter guess ")
      (flush-output)
      ;; this define is ill defined I suppose.
      ;; you can only define at the start of lexical scope or the global env.
      (let ((guess (string->number (read-line))))
        (if (not (integer? guess))
            (begin
              (display "Invalid input. Please enter a valid number.")
              (newline)
              (loop attempts-left low high)))
        (if (= guess target)
            (begin
              (display "Correct! ")
              (display attempts)
              (display " guesses... Please enter your name:")
              (newline)
              (let ((name (read-line)))
                (display "Good game, ")
                (display name)
                (newline)
                (newline))
              (play-again name 5))) ;; still a magic number!
        (if (< guess target)
            (begin
              (display "Higher...")
              (newline)
              (loop (- attempts-left 1) guess high))
            (begin
              (display "Lower...")
              (newline)
              (loop (- attempts-left 1) low guess))))))))

;; third increment:

(define (play-again
          name      ;; the name may carry over
          attempts) ;; the attempts may carry over
  (display "Would you like to play again? [y/n]")
  (let ((in (read-line)))
    (if (and (string? in)
             (or (string=? "y")    ;; the user wants to enter. We may
                 (string=? "Y"))) ;; reuse its name afterwards.
        (guess-game (random target-maximum) 5) ;; magic numbers would be configured
        ;; at another place and reused here.
        ;; the following line is the else:
        (display "good bye, then!"))))

(define (guess-game target attempts)
  (display "Guess a number from 1 to 100:") ;; exclusive?
  (newline)
  (let loop ((attempts-left attempts)
             (low 1)
             (high 100))
    (if (= attempts-left 0)
        (begin
          (display "Out of attempts. The correct number was ")
          (display target)
          (newline)
          (display "Please enter your name:")
          (newline)
          (let ((name (read-line)))
            (display "Good game, ")
            (display name)
            (newline)
            (newline)
            (+ (random target-maximum) 1) ;; this line was returning a random integer.
            (play-again name 5))) ;; still a magic number!
    (begin
      (display "Enter guess ")
      (flush-output)
      ;; this define is ill defined I suppose.
      ;; you can only define at the start of lexical scope or the global env.
      (let ((guess (string->number (read-line))))
        (cond ((not (integer? guess))
               (display "Invalid input. Please enter a valid number.")
               (newline)
               (loop attempts-left low high))
              ((string? guess) ;; ordering of conditions are relevant.
               (error (string-append "unexpected input: " guess)))
              ((= guess target)
               (display "Correct! ")
               (display attempts)
               (display " guesses... Please enter your name:")
               (newline)
               (let ((name (read-line)))
                 (display "Good game, ")
                 (display name)
                 (newline)
                 (newline))
               (play-again name 5)) ;; still a magic number!
              ((< guess target)
               (display "Higher...")
               (newline)
               (loop (- attempts-left 1) guess high))
              (else
                (display "Lower...")
                (newline)
                (loop (- attempts-left 1) low guess))))))))
  
(guess-game(+ (random target-maximum) 1) 5)
```

Comment: your loop should be transformed to a tail-recursive function as well. My code is bad but each increment should teach you at least something.